# Jump off of \ jump off the rock

Tags: grammaticality

I have seen both types of sentences:

> He **jumped off** the rock.
>
> He **jumped off of** the rock.

Are they both grammatical?

Explain.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you please use a forward slash (`/`) when separating options? A backslash isn't used for that purpose in English.

Answer (score 3):

You “jump off“ ***of*** (=from) a surface,  so  *‘jump off of the rock’* and *‘jump off the rock’* are both grammatical, the former is more common in speech but the latter sounds better and less redundant to my ears.

The following guidance is off of [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/off_of)

> The use of ***off of*** as a preposition is now considered tautological or incorrect by some usage guides and is not suitable for formal or business use. *Off of* can be replaced with *on*, *from* or *off*:
>
> 1. "This is based on (based off of) his first book"
> 2. "He took a paper off (off of) his desk".
> 3. "I got the information from ("off of") the Internet"

and from [Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/off--of) we have this

> USAGE NOTE
>   The phrasal preposition *off of* is old in English, going back to the 16th century. Although usage guides reject it as redundant, recommending *off* without *of*, the phrase is widespread in speech, including that of the educated: *Let's watch as the presidential candidates come **off of** the rostrum and down into the audience*.
>   *Off of* is rare in edited writing except to give the flavor of speech.

Other examples with *off of* are

- Don't take your eyes off of the road.
- Can I borrow ten dollars off of you?

Comment: what is meaning of off of

Comment: @KshitijSingh it just means "off" I added the links, visit the pages :) If that comment was a joke, good one!

Comment: It wan not a joke, I really wanted to know its meaning

Comment: @KshitijSingh you asked "…meaning **of off of**, so I guessed you were *fooling* around. In any case, "off" is the opposite of "on". If I jump *off* a chair, I am no longer on it. Some people will add an "of" so you can hear *I jumped off of a chair* The meaning is the same.

Comment: To me as a Briton, “off of” sounds American but not UK or Commonwealth; given that you say it goes way back, I suppose this could be a case where the US is more conservative, though maybe it is also influenced by other languages: consider spoken German “Er sprang runter vom Tisch” (or “vom Tisch runter”), where the “vom” could lend support to this usage of “of”.

Comment: @PJTraill I don't know the answer to that but I think it's used by Brits  as well. Maybe the Americans use it more often? It might make for an interesting question on EL&U, feel free to link it back here!